# Does difficulty affect Keywarden spawn chance?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does the spawn chance of the keywardens in acts 1-4 depend on the difficulty, e.g. they spawn only if difficulty >= Torment I? Additionally, does a higher difficulty yield higher spawn chances? If so, what are the chances in numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keywardens always spawn in the appropriate regions if game difficulty is set to Torment I or above. The only chance that is effected by difficulty is the infernal machine drop rate. I could however not find any reliable source on actual numbers for drop rate per torment level.

Comment: I think you mean "key" rate. There's plenty of sources with the drop rates, but I'm on my phone right now

Comment: They drop Infernal Machines instead of keys as of patch 2.3. Also I could not find any _reliable_ source on the drop rates. If you have one, please provide it. Would be much appreciated

Comment: Seriously?? I haven't played D3 in a while...

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read, [this](http://www.diablowiki.net/Keywarden) seems to be the only piece of information I could find. It states that, while being a `Torment only event`, the rates to drop do increase when on a higher difficulty:

```
Key drop odds per difficulty level:
Torment I: 25%
Torment II: 28%
Torment III: 33%
Torment IV: 38%
Torment V: 43%
Torment VI: 50%
```

**EDIT:** Also, this is what I've found regarding the later Torment Tiers:

```
Torment 7: +1900% EXP, 5% chance of 2 DBs per Elite*, 5% chance for 2 Rift Keys per Guardian, 3 Horadric Cache materials, 60% chance of 1 machine from KWs, 50% chance of 2 Organs per Uber.
Torment 8: +2300% EXP, 10% chance of 2 DBs per Elite*, 15% chance of 2 Rift Keys per Guardian, 3 Horadric Cache materials, 70% chance of 1 machine from KWs, 90% chance of 2 organs per Uber.
Torment 9:+2750% EXP, 20% chance of 2 DBs per Elite*, 25% chance of 2 Rift Keys per Guardian, 4 Horadric Cache materials, 80% chance of 1 machine from KWs / 10% chance of 2 machines from KWs, 50% chance of 3 organs per Uber.
Torment 10:+3300% EXP, 33% chance of 2 DBs per Elite, 50% chance of 2 Rift Keys per Guardian, 4 Horadric Cache materials, chance for bonus Cache legs**, 90% chance of 1 machine from KWs / 33% chance of 2 machines from KWs, 90% chance of 3 organs per Uber.
```

Comment: This information seems to be outdated as it does not include drop rates for difficulty levels Torment VII to X

Comment: @Contra0x2F I'll see what I can find for you. But at the very least, those are the drop rates up to Torment 6.

Comment: @Contra0x2F Please see my edit regarding KW rates for torment 7 onwards.

Comment: Nice, you got a source on that?

Comment: This is one of the links I found, although there's plenty on the web with the same information : http://www.diabloii.net/blog/comments/torment-7-10-benefits-of-higher-difficulty